# No output in Python console when using PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, standalone

When I run my code in QGIS Python console I get output, but when I run my code from normal console I didn't get any output.

Why does it work only in QGIS Python console?

```py
import sys, os

sys.path.append(r'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/python/plugins')
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = 'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.16\\share\\proj'

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *

qgispath = r'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis'
 
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgispath, True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

path = r'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/POLSKA/PRG_PunktyAdresowe_POLSKA.shp' 
lyr = QgsVectorLayer (path, 'PRG_PunktyAdresowe_POLSKA', 'ogr')

for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    print(f.attributes())
    break
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: On your second image I do not see `break` command. Can you try using it?

Comment: the same, didnt get any output..

Comment: What if you try `print(lyr)` before `for`-loop. What does it give you?

Comment: >>> print(lyr)
<QgsMapLayer: 'PRG_PunktyAdresowe_POLSKA' (ogr)>

Comment: Try `print(lyr.featureCount())` before `for`loop. I think there are no entities or it can't read and iterate on your layer

Comment: >>> print(lyr.featureCount())
7806075

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your last screenshot where we see the Python interpreter in an interactive session you have not actually started execution of the loop yet. Hit the Enter key one more time.